# Redirect user to Captcha after X failed login attempts

Tags: asp.net

How do I count how many times a page has been loaded? If the user fails to login after X times, I want to redirect to a Captcha page with the login button disabled.

Comment: Use session to store the count of login failure.

Comment: i want to implement session count in page_load(). when x times login is failure i have to redirect with captcha login page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set the number of logins in the Session. Although this can be circumvented by the bot having cookies disabled, and realistically be more an inconvenience to users than to actual bots. Giving a number of attempts per hour per user name, and storing the attempts in the database is a more full-proof plan. Although the more involved approach, it gives you more flexibility later on for looking at user statistics.

Comment: i want to implement session count in page_load(). when x times login is failure i have to redirect with captcha login page.